# Stretch a video in p5.js?

Tags: p5.js

I have a video playing on top of my p5.js canvas. The aspect ratio of my video is 4:3, but I want to stretch the video so that it always fills the entire window whenever the window is resized, no matter what the aspect ratio of the video is.

When I use `video.size(x, y)` to try to change the size, the video always maintains its 4:3 aspect ratio, leaving it always pillarboxed/letterboxed.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stretch a video to the size of the window with p5.js:

1. create a canvas with the size of the window by using `createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight)`
2. paint the entire canvas with the video by using `image(vid, 0, 0, width, height)`
3. resize the canvas when the window resizes by using`resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight)` and `windowResized()`

You can take a look at the code and the demo here: [https://glitch.com/~p5-js-play-video-full-window](https://glitch.com/%7Ep5-js-play-video-full-window)